# Babel ES6 Class with default destructured parameters are undefined

Tags: default, destructuring, es6-class

I have a ES6 class with default parameters like so:

```
constructor({
    // defaults
    defaultOne     = 'default value one',
    defaultTwo     = ['default','value','two],
    defaultThree   = 'default value three,
}) {
    this.defaultOne   = defaultOne
    this.defaultTwo   = defaultTwo
    this.defaultThree = defaultThree

    return this
}
```

When I create an instance of the class it works as expected when I provide values.

```
new Class({defaultOne: 'one',defaultTwo: ['t','w','o'], defaultThree: 'three'})
```

But when I instantiate an instance with no values:

```
new Class()
```

It throws an undefined error.  This approach seems to work fine with standard function declarations/expressions.  Any idea what I'm missing here?

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Answer (score 4):

I agree it's a bit ugly, but it happens because babel transpiles this to something like:

```js
constructor(_ref) {
  var _defaultOne = _ref.defaultOne; // « this is where it goes wrong. _ref = undefined
}
```

You are setting defaults for the object properties, but not an default for the object itself. So this is fixable. It would be nice if babel did this for us, but it doesn't.

To fix this, provide a default for the argument object, instead of:

```js
// es6
const foo = ({ bar = 'baz' }) => {};

// transpiled
var foo = function foo(_ref) {
  var _ref$bar = _ref.bar;
  var bar = _ref$bar === undefined ? 'baz' : _ref$bar;
};
```

You need to write

```js
// es6
const foo = ({ bar = 'baz'} = {}) => {};

// transpiled
var foo = function foo() {
  var _ref = arguments.length <= 0 || arguments[0] === undefined ? {} : arguments[0];

  var _ref$bar = _ref.bar;
  var bar = _ref$bar === undefined ? 'baz' : _ref$bar;
};
```

To be complete, your example would become:

```js
constructor({
  // defaults
  defaultOne     = 'default value one',
  defaultTwo     = ['default','value','two'],
  defaultThree   = 'default value three',
} = {}) { // « notice the change on this line
  this.defaultOne   = defaultOne
  this.defaultTwo   = defaultTwo
  this.defaultThree = defaultThree
}

new Class({defaultOne: 'one',defaultTwo: ['t','w','o'], defaultThree: 'three'})
new Class()
```

Answer (score 0):

While it doesn't seem the spec allows you to deconstruct a class's arguments directly, this solution provides a very similar syntax:

```
class Test {
    constructor(options) {
      let {
        defaultOne   : defaultOne   = 'default one value', 
        defaultTwo   : defaultTwo   = 'default two value', 
        defaultThree : defaultThree = 'default three value'
      } = (options) ? options:{};

      this.defaultOne   = defaultOne;
      this.defaultTwo   = defaultTwo;
      this.defaultThree = defaultThree;

      this.init();
    }

  init() {
    console.log(this.defaultOne);
    console.log(this.defaultTwo);
    console.log(this.defaultThree);
  }
}

new Test({defaultOne: 'Override default one value'});
new Test();
```

[ES6 Babel test](http://jsbin.com/qarabatoni/1/edit?js,console)

[Compiled Babel ES5](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Cstage-3&code=class%20Test%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(options)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20defaultOne%20%20%20%3A%20defaultOne%20%20%20%3D%20'default%20one%20value'%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20defaultTwo%20%20%20%3A%20defaultTwo%20%20%20%3D%20'default%20two%20value'%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20defaultThree%20%3A%20defaultThree%20%3D%20'default%20three%20value'%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%3D%20(options)%20%3F%20options%3A%7B%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.defaultOne%20%20%20%3D%20defaultOne%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.defaultTwo%20%20%20%3D%20defaultTwo%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.defaultThree%20%3D%20defaultThree%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.init()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20init()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(this.defaultOne)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(this.defaultTwo)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(this.defaultThree)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Anew%20Test(%7BdefaultOne%3A%20'Override%20default%20one%20value'%7D)%3B%0Anew%20Test()%3B)